Insert new column into a new created spreadsheet using Apache POI
I have a spreadsheet file. I want to open this file and create a new spreadsheet file from its data along with inserting a new column for this new file. Currently, I just insert successfully a new column from head and tail of the current column list.
I use Apache POI 5.2.2 and already know that is impossible to insert a new column into an existing spreadsheet file. But we can insert a new column into a new created spreadsheet from that file. So, how can I insert new column from the middle of column list ?
public static void readAndCreateNewXLSXFile(String fileInput, String fileOutput, String newSpreadSheetName,
            int addColumnIndexbasedZero) {
        
        File sourcefile = new File(fileInput);
        FileInputStream inputStreamOfSource;
        XSSFWorkbook sourceWorkbook = null;

        XSSFWorkbook destWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        
        XSSFSheet destSheet = destWorkbook.createSheet(newSpreadSheetName);

        //Map<Integer, Object[]> mapDataOutput = new TreeMap<>();

        try {
            inputStreamOfSource = new FileInputStream(sourcefile);
            
            sourceWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inputStreamOfSource);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        XSSFSheet sourceSheet = (XSSFSheet) sourceWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Row newRow;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        int newRowIndex = 0;
        for (Row row : sourceSheet) {// loop through logical rows of sheet, skip empty rows

            
            // row of input source
            row = sourceSheet.getRow(rowIndex++);

            // row of output source
            newRow = destSheet.createRow(newRowIndex++);

            if (row != null) { // check for empty row

                int cellIndex = 0;
                int newCellIndexSection1 = 0;
                int newCellIndexSection2 = 0;
                int newTotalColumns = row.getLastCellNum() + 1;
                Cell newCell;

                // inserted column is at the first
                if (addColumnIndexbasedZero == row.getFirstCellNum()) {
                    newCellIndexSection1 = 0;
                    newCellIndexSection2 = 1;
                }

                // inserted column is at the last
                if (addColumnIndexbasedZero == row.getLastCellNum()) {
                    newCellIndexSection1 = 0;
                    newCellIndexSection2 = row.getLastCellNum() + 1;
                }

                // inserted column is at the middle
                if (row.getFirstCellNum() < addColumnIndexbasedZero && addColumnIndexbasedZero < row.getLastCellNum()) {
                    newCellIndexSection1 = 0;
                    newCellIndexSection2 = addColumnIndexbasedZero + 1;
                }

                
                // add new column into column list, fist | last | middle
                newCell = newRow.createCell(addColumnIndexbasedZero);
                newCell.setCellValue("test");

                for (Cell cell : row) {// loop through logical row, skip empty cells

                    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                        if (newCellIndexSection1 < addColumnIndexbasedZero) {
                            newCell = newRow.createCell(newCellIndexSection1++);
                            newCell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        if (newCellIndexSection2 < newTotalColumns) {
                            newCell = newRow.createCell(newCellIndexSection2++);
                            newCell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        }

                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        // Write the workbook in file system
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileOutput));
            destWorkbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("file.xlsx written successfully");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

original spreadsheet
result of inserting from the middle (new column is the second one of new spreadsheet) 
